# Pygame window resizing isn't working correctly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a resizable window in pygame. However, it's been resizing randomly and incorrectly.

I have two files, this is the one that runs the main loop:

```
import eaterConstants

Screen = eaterConstants.Screen([400,400])
while True:
    Screen.getGlobalInput()
```

This is the relevant class that is referenced in the first file:

```
class Screen():
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.RESIZABLE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self.updated = False

    def getGlobalInput(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                self.resize(event)
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        self.update()

    def resize(self,event):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.size,pygame.RESIZABLE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self.updated = False

    def update(self):
        if self.updated == False:
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.updated = True
```

This is what the problem looks like generally speaking:
https://youtu.be/HBFz-yeEpdU

The expected result is that of any other window you could have on your computer(try resizing your web browser for instance)

I'm on linux 16.04. I don't know if that's relevant or not.

Edit: Turns out that using (event.w, event.h) over event.size doesn't work. It still has the above posted jittering bug.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pass the width and height, [see the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34110792/667648).

Comment: Oh apparently the event size seems to be different from the width and height. I was under the impression that size simply gave a tuple of (w,h) which either isn't included in the documentation or I missed it.

When I wrote the question I wasn't able to find the other thread on it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Whelp, turns out that wasn't the issue.