# Is there a way to resize properly game's screen?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Every time I try to resize the PyGame window, there's no resizing of the game, it keeps like before, and there's just more background.

Any idea about how to resize the game's output with the window (and keeping the ratio, too ), is there a method or do I just need to hand code it?

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603222/allowing-resizing-window-pygame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to code it yourself.

Draw your game not directly on the display surface, but on an intermediate one that you can resize to the display surface's size.

Here's a simple example:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300),HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
    game_screen = screen.copy()
    pic = pygame.surface.Surface((50, 50))
    pic.fill('dodgerblue')

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT: 
                return
            elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                ratio = game_screen.get_rect().width / game_screen.get_rect().height
                new_size = event.size[0], int(event.size[0] / ratio)
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(new_size, HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)

        game_screen.fill('black')
        game_screen.blit(pic, (100, 100))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(game_screen, screen.get_rect().size), (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
    
main()
```

Comment: I see, I've to make something like this manually. Thank you very much for your quick help!